# uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options (NameError)

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, capybara

Needed to execute the below set of code. Please refer my code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :logging_selenium_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(loggingPrefs:
  {browser: 'ALL'})
  browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: 
  browser_options, desired_capabilities: caps)
end
```

but keeps on getting

> **uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options (NameError)**

Anyone having any idea what might be causing this!!!

Comment: I think there is not `loggingPrefs` option. What do yo want to do?

Comment: I am trying to get console logs using Ruby & Capybara/Selenium. Someone suggested to use this method, but
    browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
gives out the error as stated in the question. I am able to access `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome` module hierarchy but on scope-resoluting `Options`
it gives out the NameSpaceError. I also looked into the selenium files and saw for myself `Options` definition but couldn't use it in my code https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/options.rb.

Answer (score 6):

`::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options` was added in selenium-webdriver 3.4.1 -  Upgrade to the latest `selenium-webdriver` gem (3.5.2 currently)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to `Capybara` for declaring `browser_options`. see the below:

```
Capybara.register_driver :logging_selenium_chrome do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(loggingPrefs:
  {browser: 'ALL'})
  browser_options = Capybara::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new()
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: 
  browser_options, desired_capabilities: caps)
end
```